# How can I make broadly applicable code that fills missing elements differently according to the variable types?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am supposed to fill missing values of a lot of CSV files.
Normally, those have almost the same variables.

Here are the conditions that I should satisfy.

1. If the value type is numeric (int or float) I should fill -1 to the missing value.
2. If the value type is character I should fill m to the missing value.
3. If the value type is time (e.g., 08:00) I should not fill anything (leave it as blank)

The problem is that Each CSV file has **different** variables in detail. For example,
Data_1 is

```
v1 v2 v3  v4  v5
1  a  d     
2  b     3.2  07:00
   d  a  7.6  08:00
2     d  8.0
```

then it should be

```
v1 v2 v3  v4    v5
1  a  d  -1 
2  b  m  3.2   07:00
-1 d  a  7.6   08:00
2  m  d  8.0
```

However, each data is different in that,

```
v1 v2 v3 v5
1  a  d   
2  b     07:00
   d  a  09:00
2     d
```

or

```
v5      v6
        x
 03:00  y
 06:00  
        d
```

Therefore, I want to generate code that can uniformly apply to many CSVs that have characteristics above.
I tried fillna for example,

```
def filldefault(series):
  series.fillna('m' if type(series.iloc[0]) == str else -1, inplace = True)
```

However, this cannot handle the time variable.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def fill_series(series: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(series):
        return series.fillna(-1)

    if pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(series):
        # Condition that matches the simple string scenario
        if all(series.dropna().str.len() == 1):
            return series.fillna("m")

        # Non-NA values match a format "XX:XX"
        if all(series.dropna().str.fullmatch("\d\d:\d\d")):
            # Don't do anything
            return series

    # Raised if none of the above conditions are met
    raise ValueError("Unknown series format")

# Then apply this function to all series in the dataframe
df = df.apply(fill_series)
```

This way you explicitly check for the type and/or content of each series before you fill missing values. Note that I check for the *dtype* of the whole column, not *type* of the first element – as that one can be missing. You'll probably need to adjust the conditions for each series type to fit your data.

Comment: Sorry but it generates "Unknown series format" as you suggested.

This is what I obtain when I did .info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2252 entries, 0 to 2251
Columns: 772 entries, placekey to home_number_300
dtypes: float64(422), int64(18), object(332)
memory usage: 13.3+ MB

If only the value does not look like "\d\d:\d\d"
I want to add -1 or m according to the way it looks.

I added
    if pd.api.types.is_float_dtype(series):
        return series.fillna(-1)
but it did not work.

Comment: @PeterPark Could you provide a concrete example of the series that throws this error?